# Can't control the metric of Google Sheets API with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using NodeJS for my project, which is listing all files shared with people out of the domain and list them in a Google Sheets.

My problem is that I have a lot of files and a lot of pages when I list all my drive, and my function doesn't want to wait to write data in Google Sheets and just list all of them, detect files out of the domain and write. At the end, metric of Google Sheets blocks me:

> code: 429,   errors: [
> {
> message: "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Write requests' and limit 'Writ e requests per minute per user' of service
> 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:XXXXXXXXX'.",
> domain: 'global',
> reason: 'rateLimitExceeded'
> }   ]

Or just too fast to write all data and after some files, stop writing in my Google Sheets.

I try to set a timeout, but I don't understand why he won't take it.
Here is my code, can someone help me to write all my files or explain to me if I did something wrong with my code?

Here is my main function who checks all files and if a file is shared out of domain, call my function to write in the Google Sheets generate before

```
function exportDataFileOOD(nextPageToken, auth) {
    const service = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
    service.files.list({
            corpora: 'user',
            includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
            pageSize: 30,
            pageToken: nextPageToken,
            supportsAllDrives: true,
            q: '\'me\' in owners and not trashed',
            fields: 'nextPageToken,files(name,id,webViewLink,permissions, shared)'
    }, (err, res) => {

    if (err) {
        return console.error('The API returned an error:', err.message);
    }

    let files = res.data.files
    nextPageToken = res.data.nextPageToken

    files.forEach((file) => {
            if(file.shared === true){

            let fileOOD = new Boolean(false);
            let permissionList = file.permissions

            permissionList.forEach((permission) => {
                if (permission.emailAddress){
                    let mailSplit = permission.emailAddress.split('@')

                    if (mailSplit[1] !== 'DOMAIN') {
                        fileOOD = Boolean(true);
                    }
                }
            })

            if (fileOOD === true) {
                writeData(file)
                sleep(10000)
            }
        }
    })

        if(nextPageToken){
            exportDataFileOOD(nextPageToken)
        }
    })
}
```

And here is my writing function:

```
    function writeData(file){
        columns[0].value.push(file.name)
        columns[1].value.push(file.webViewLink)

        file.permissions.forEach((permission) => {
            if (permission.role === "owner") {
                columns[2].value.push(permission.emailAddress);
            } else if (permission.role === "writer") {
                columns[3].value.push(permission.emailAddress);
            } else if (permission.role === "reader") {
                columns[4].value.push(permission.emailAddress)
            } else if (permission.role === "commenter") {
                columns[5].value.push(permission.emailAddress)
            } else {
                console.log("Error about this user permission: " + permission.email + " is " + permission.role)
            }
        })

        let auth = callAPI("USER@DOMAIN")
        columns.forEach((column) => {
            const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth})

            if (column.value !== "") {
                sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
                    spreadsheetId: idSheets,
                    requestBody: {
                        valueInputOption: "RAW",
                        data: [{
                            range: column.letter + line,
                            values: [[
                                String(column.value)
                            ]]
                        }]
                    }
                }, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                })
            }
        })

        columns.forEach((column) => {
            column.value = [];
        })
        line++
    }
```

Thanks for your help !

Edit:

I have some update on my script, I can know write in the sheets without error with a sleep() function, but now I want to check file of a list of user and the script continue to be fast and I can't use the sleep() function for all my users because i have some with 0 file and some with a lot of file

I can't apply a sleep() for 30minutes, because it will takes a week to finish. So if someone know how to wait the end of a forEach loop to continue ?

My forEach loop:

```
let users = promise.users

            users.forEach((user) => {
                    exportDataFileOOD(null, callAPI(user.primaryEmail))
            })
```

Edit2:

My column variable

```
let columns = [
    {
        letter: "A",
        title: "Name",
        value: []
    }, {
        letter: "B",
        title: "Link",
        value: []
    }, {
        letter: "C",
        title: "Owner(s)",
        value: []
    }
];
```

Comment: Have you checked on the [Resolve time-based quota errors](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits#exponential) that suggests to use the [Retry strategy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/retry-strategy)? You can also check on [Request a quota increase](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits#increase)

Comment: No i didn't check.

Comment: I have some update on my script, i can know write in the sheets without error with a sleep() function, but now i want to check a list of user, perhaps the script continue to be fast and i can't use the sleep() function for all my users because i have some with 0 file and some with a lot of file

I can't apply a sleep() for 30minutes, because it will takes a week to finish. So if someone know how to wait the end of a forEach loop to continue ?

Comment: About `because it will takes a week to finish`, in your situation, approximately, how many files do you want to check? And, what is `column.letter`?

Comment: I don't know how many files exactly, but for example I have an account with 1To of drive file.

Column is a variable, made an edit to show this variable. I write each column I need, with letter for specify in each batchupdate the column + line

In my writing function, in requestBody > data:
`range: column.letter + line`

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I don't know how many files exactly`, in this case, I thought that when I could know an approximate number of files, it might help think of the modification direction. I apologize for this. And, I cannot understand `but for example, I have an account with 1To of drive file.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, in your script, `columns` is not declared. How about this? When you reply, when `@` is added to the user name like `@name`, the user can notice your reply.

Comment: Regarding the script, you are making a batch request for each column needed to be created and filled, have you tried to first gather all the data and then create one single request to set the sheet?

Comment: @Tanaike: I check a list of users, users haven't filed shared out of the domain and for example, I have a user with approximately 500 files shared out of the domain.

Comment: @Kessy: Yes I make a request for each column. I don't know how to set the Sheets with one single request yet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Sorry for not giving an answer in a while, but the project was on stand-by, I'm gonna see your answer and tell you if it's help me.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, each row is put into Spreadsheet by Sheets API in the loop. I think that this is the reason for your current issue of `rateLimitExceeded`. At "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate" of Sheets API, multiple rows can be put to Spreadsheet by one API call.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

In this modification, the following flow is used.

1. Retrieve the file list.
2. Create an array for putting to a Spreadsheet from the retrieved file list.
3. Put the array to Spreadsheet using "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate".

#### Modified script:

In this modification, please run `main(auth)`. And, please set the variables in `main`.

```js
// This function is used for retrieving the file list.
function getFileList(drive, pageToken) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    drive.files.list(
      {
        corpora: "user",
        includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
        pageSize: 1000,
        pageToken,
        supportsAllDrives: true,
        q: "'me' in owners and trashed=false",
        fields: "nextPageToken,files(name,id,webViewLink,permissions,shared)",
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err.errors);
          return;
        }
        resolve(res.data);
      }
    );
  });
}

// Please run this function.
async function main(auth) {
  const service = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth }); // Please set your client.
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth }); // Please set your client.
  const idSheets = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
  const row = 2; // Please set the row number you want to put the values to Spreadsheet.


  console.log("--- Retrieve file list.");
  let files = [];
  let pageToken = "";
  do {
    const res = await getFileList(service, pageToken);
    if (res.files.length > 0) {
      files = [...files, ...res.files];
      console.log(files.length); // Showing process.
    }
    pageToken = res.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  console.log(files.length);
  console.log("--- Retrieved file list.");

  console.log("--- Create values.");
  const values = files.reduce((ar, file) => {
    if (file.shared === true) {
      file.permissions.forEach((permission) => {
        if (permission.emailAddress) {
          let mailSplit = permission.emailAddress.split("@");
          if (mailSplit[1] !== "DOMAIN") {
            file.permissions.forEach((permission) => {
              const columns = [ file.name, file.webViewLink, ...Array(4).fill("") ];
              if (permission.role === "owner") {
                columns[2] = permission.emailAddress || "";
              } else if (permission.role === "writer") {
                columns[3] = permission.emailAddress || "";
              } else if (permission.role === "reader") {
                columns[4] = permission.emailAddress || "";
              } else if (permission.role === "commenter") {
                columns[5] = permission.emailAddress || "";
              } else {
                console.log("Error about this user permission: " + permission.email + " is " + permission.role);
              }
              ar.push(columns);
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  console.log(values.length);
  console.log("--- Created values, and put values to Spreadsheet.");

  if (values.length == 0) return;
  const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({ spreadsheetId: idSheets, requestBody: { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED", data: [{ range: `A${row}`, values }]} }).catch(({ errors }) => console.error(errors));
  if (!res) return;
  console.log("--- Done.");
}
```

- When `main(auth)` is run, the file list is retrieved, and an array for putting to Spreadsheet is created. And, the array is put into Spreadsheet by one API call. By this, I thought that your current issue of `rateLimitExceeded` might be able to be removed.

#### Note:

- From your script, I used "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate". If you want to append the values to Spreadsheet, I think that ["Method: spreadsheets.values.append"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) might be able to be used.
- Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual Spreadsheet. So, when the above script was not your expected result, can you provide your expected situation of the Spreadsheet as an image? By this, I would like to modify the script.
- From your showing script, the values are put to the 1st tab of Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)